# HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("External") suddenly returns null on Azure Webb App

Tags: azure, owin, tls1.2

I have several applications running on Azure Web Apps that uses Microsoft Azure Ad authentication. Theese have been working flawlessly until now August 2022. But all of a sudden they all have problems retreiving login info from Microsoft-Login using Azure AD Multitenant and all tennants have issues.

Appregistrations and Secrets are not Expired.

I could replicate the problem using my own iis, but when I used the reg "hack" to enforce the use of TLS 1.2, it is working locally again...
However the Web Apps still have the issue... HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("External"); returns null... I suspect it has to do with the TLS, but the Web Apps are set to use TLS 1.2.

So after hours of testing everything I'll give it a go and ask here.

Thanks
/Håkan

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. All of my hosted asp.net web applications stopped authenticating with MS AD on Aug 5, 2022, in the afternoon.

I got the idea from your post, that this may be because I am using TLS 1.1. After some more research, I found an Alert card on MS Azure Home -> Overview -

"Upcoming TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 3DES deprecation
Please enable support for TLS 1.2 on clients(applications/platform) to avoid any service impact.
[Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/enable-support-tls-environment?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_IAM&tabs=azure-monitor)"

I will try to upgrade my applications to use TLS 1.2 and hope this issue will get resolved.

Kind regards,
Arvind Khanna

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I get this when I set my time from Windows command prompt to incorrect time. Then when I corrected it, I had to reboot the computer and it starts working again.